# Blueprism Spying Problems

Tags: blueprism

I am trying to spy a pop-up. But I couldn't recognize any element using any spy mode(Even I tried region mode)on the pop-up. It was throwing an error "Can't perform any spying operation". When I inspect the popup it was created using JQuery Event Handlers. Does anyone know how to solve the spying operation?

Answer (score 0):

There are two reasons why this might be occurring:

- **Your system's OLEACC.DLL file is not properly registered** - More information is available [here](https://portal.blueprism.com/customer-support/knowledge-base/active-accessibility-aa-spy-mode-missing-will-not-detect-elements) on how to resolve this, but the solution boils down to the following:

  > - Open a Command Prompt (CMD.EXE) with Administrator privileges
  > - Navigate within that to the location of your OLEACC.DLL file (usually 'C:\Windows\System32' directory)
  > - Run the following command to re-register the DLL file:
  >     `regsvr32 OLEACC.DLL`
- **The window is created in the window hierarchy in such a way that it technically doesn't reside within the application you're attached to** - Popups generated by certain web applications are not spyable using HTML mode. Instead, you'll have to create an entirely new object with new attaching logic to be able to spy this particular window. More information on this issue is available at the following resources:

  - [Blue Prism Knowledge Base Article - 'The window spied was not found in the model' error when spying](https://portal.blueprism.com/customer-support/knowledge-base/window-spied-was-not-found-model-error-when-spying)
  - Blue Prism Browser Automation Guide

Comment: Not directly related to the question, but sometimes blueprism can only spy native browser windows with acessibility mode, while in fact win32 mode works just as well, if you use external tools to find attributes you need and type them in manually. Same issues with java mode.